# Thread safe read from listbox object possible?

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety

I have stored objects in a listbox. I want to READ (Not write or edit) these objects from different threads. Is this threadsafe? And if not, how would I make it threadsafe?

I tried writing a threadsafe function, but this obviously does not return a value on all exits.

```
Private Delegate Function GetDetailsDelegate(ByVal index As Integer)
Private Function GetDetails(index As Integer) As MySQLDetails
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New GetDetailsDelegate(AddressOf GetDetails), {index})
    Else
        Return LstMySQL.Items.Item(index)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You should store the data in a variable rather than using a control.

Comment: This means storing the data twice, since I also want to display in a listbox.

Comment: Yes. It won't hurt the computer, and it will make the programming much easier.

Comment: Thanks, This doesn't answer my question though. Is reading from a listbox threadsafe?

Comment: The ["Recommendations for class libraries"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices#recommendations-for-class-libraries) section of "Managed threading best practices" (by Microsoft) says ".NET class libraries are not thread safe by default." I couldn't find anthing in the documentation (and links therefrom) for the ListBox that said anything about it being thread-safe. I got the *impression* that if you populated the ListBox from a read-only collection then reads would be thread-safe. But then the data is available in a variable...